# Multer is uploading my image locally but not in my database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I Want to upload a image on my blog post and there is an error, image is alredy in the folder but when i see the database there is noimage.png set as default ...
Im using Multer , there is my code :

Addpost.ejs

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
<form method="POST" action="/posts/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category">
            <% categories.forEach(function(category){ %>
                <option value="<%= category.title %>"><%= category.title %></option>
            <%  }) %>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Body</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="body"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Main Image</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="file" type="file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Author</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="author">
            <option value="Arsen Cenko">Arsen Cenko</option>
            <option value="John Doe">John Doe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" name
    ="submit" type="submit" value="save">
</form>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

PostSchema :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
category: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category"
    }
],
body: String,
file: String })
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
```

Post.js Route

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var Post = require("../models/post");
var Category = require("../models/category");
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
   destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public/images/uploads/')
   },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)) 
  } });
 var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


 router.get("/add", function(req, res) {
     Category.find({}, function(err, categories){
         if(err){
            console.log(err);
         } else{
            res.render("addpost", {
                title: "Add Post",
                categories: categories
            })
         }
     })
})


router.post("/add", upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
var title       = req.body.title;
var category    = req.body.category;
var body        = req.body.body;
var author      = req.body.author;

if(req.files && req.files.image){
    var imageOriginalName = req.files.image.originalname;
    var imageName = req.files.image.fieldname;
    var imageMime = req.files.image.mimetype;
    var imagePath = req.files.image.path;
    var imageExt = req.files.image.extension;
    var imageSize = req.files.image.size;
} else {
    var imageName = "noimage.png";
}

var newPost = {title:title, category:category, body:body, author:author, image:imageName};

Post.create(newPost, function(err, newPost){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error");
    } else{
        res.redirect("/");
    }
})
```

})

Thanks :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Hey according to documentation

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

using `upload.single('image')` will get your file in "req.file" not in "req.files"

I think this is the reason your if case fails and jumps to else case. You cannot access it like req.file.image.filename you can simply access it via req.file.filename. Since it is already a "single" file. try console logging the req.file to know what you are getting.

**update** I think mistake is in your html

```
<input class="form-control" name="file" type="file">
```

should be

```
 <input class="form-control" name="image" type="file">
```

the name attribute of the html should be same as the string in upload.single. 
So in your case

```
upload.single('image')
```

Now you will receive file in req.file.

Hope it helps.